# Prove that if a polynomial $P$ has no roots in the upper half plane, then so does $P'$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Prove that if a polynomial $P$ has no roots in the upper half plane, then so does $P'$

This is a part of an exam preparation and I would appreciate a hint. My approach was to use Rouche's theorem but it didn't help so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the fact stated in the question is used to *prove* the Gauss-Lucas theorem, it should  have a   proof independent of that theorem. Which is  easy to give: write $P(z)=c\prod_{k=1}^n (z-z_k) $, then
$$\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{z-z_k}\tag1$$

---

> The above is a hint.
>
> Complete proof is below.

---

By assumption, $\operatorname{Im}z_k\le 0$ for all $k$. When  $\operatorname{Im}z>0$, we have $\operatorname{Im}(z-z_k)>0$ and therefore $\operatorname{Im}\frac{1}{z-z_k}<0$ for all $k$. The conclusion is
$$\operatorname{Im}\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}<0\tag2$$

Answer (score 3):

According to the Gauss-Lucas theorem, the zeroes of $P'$ are contained in the convex hull of the zeroes of $P$.

Comment: If I map ask, what does $P'$ mean?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with this theorem, I guess (and hope) this is why I couldn't solve that.

Comment: @PyRulez: $P'$ is the deriative