If $p$ is a polynomial with $deg(p) >1$ with roots $x$ all having $Re(x)>0$, then so does $p'$
I'm trying to prove the following:
Let $p$ be a polynomial, $deg(p)>1$, over $\mathbb{C}$, whose roots lie in the right half plane of $\mathbb{C}$: if $x$ is a root of $p$ then $Re(x)>0$.
Therefore:  all the roots of the derivative ($p'$), are on the right plane too.
This is how far I've got:
$p'(z) = p(z) \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}\big(\frac{1}{1-x_k}\big)$, where $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^n$ are the roots of $p(z)$.
This is true from Leibniz's formula for the derivative of a product.
We know that $p(z)=0$ only for $z\in \{z:Re(z)>0\}$, all that remains now is to show that $\sum_{k=1}^n \big( \frac{1}{z-x_k} \big) \ne 0$ for $z\in \{z:Re(z)\le 0\}$.
This is where I get stuck...
*(Edit Important remark): this is an exercise for the beginning of a first complex analysis course, so the solution shouldn't be something that requires techniques of complex derivatives, and more advanced subjects in the field of complex analysis.

There is a proof in Gauss–Lucas theorem

Also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3812651/42969, and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/454039/42969

The Gauss-Lucas theorem states that if $p$ is a polynomial with roots $z_1,\ldots,z_k$, then the roots of the derivative are contained in the convex hull generated by $z_1,\ldots,z_k$. It is therefore enough to prove that $Re(z)>0$ is a convex set (and hence the convex hull generated by $z_1,\ldots,z_k$ will be contained in $Re(z)>0$, which implies the roots of the derivative will also be contained there). Indeed, if $z_1,z_2\in Re(z)>0$ and $t\in [0,1]$, then $Re(tz_1+(1-t)z_2)=tRe(z_1)+(1-t)Re(z_2)>0$.
